# Best Way to Toggle the Menu With Menu Button And Click Outside method

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have a menu button on the header and slide menu from the right side of the screen, I made the code when I clicked on the menu button the slide menu exit from the right, but I can't do this:

- when the menu is open if I clicked outside of the slider, the slider do that behavior
- And also I cant be able to chick on the menu button on the header and open the slide menu

  ```
     <Slide direction= 'left' in= {this.props.DrawerOpen}>
     ------Some Code------
     </Slide>


     <div className="header-bg">
         <IconButton
             onClick={() => this.props.drawerHandleClick()}
             style={{outline:'none', color: 'white', float:'right', marginRight:'20px'}}>
             <MenuIcon/>
         </IconButton>
     </div>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to install `use-onclickoutside` and do this for the `Slide` component:

```
import useOnClickOutside from 'use-onclickoutside';

const SlideRef = React.useRef(null);
useOnClickOutside(SlideRef, () => {
    setDrawerOpen(false);
});

<Slide
   direction= 'left' 
   ref={SlideRef}
   in= {this.props.DrawerOpen}
>
------Some Code------
</Slide>
```

And  do this where the `IconButton` is:

```
const [drawerOpen, setDrawerOpen] = useState(false);
const drawerHandleClick = () => setDrawerOpen(!drawerOpen);
```